# Connecting an Azure VM to active directory domain behind ISP NAT

Tags: active-directory, web-server, exchange, nat, azure

I have an active directory local domain set up with 2 DC's running DHCP and DNS. Because my ISP uses NAT there is no way to host services externally. How can I link an Azure VM into my local active directory to host exchange and a web server?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the answer you're looking for is [an Azure site-to-site VPN](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-network/?rnd=1).  Considering your size (2 DCs, ISP with NAT), you might want to consider [Office 365 for Business](https://blogs.office.com/2014/04/15/synchronizing-your-directory-with-office-365-is-easy/) instead of hosting your own email, however.

You also haven't said what the web server would host.  If it's just your company web site, that can really be hosted anywhere.  Unless there's a compelling reason to tie it into your local directory, I wouldn't.